# Copy cell to word file and save

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste, office-automation

Run time error 4248 while copying a cell in a new word file and saving it in VBA...I am getting error in the saveas part

```
Sub CreateWordDoc()
    Dim ExcRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Dim tosavefilename As Variant
    Dim dateformat As Variant
    Dim middle As String
    Dim creationtime As Date
    Dim Msubject As String
    MsgBox "The value of Msubject is" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
    Msubject = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
    creationtime = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value
    dateformat = VBA.Format(creationtime, "yyyy.mm.dd   hh.mm")
    middle = Replace(Msubject, ":", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "/", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "?", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "Chr(34)", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "<", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, ">", "_")
    middle = Replace(middle, "|", "_")
    MsgBox "The value of the dateformat and middle is" & dateformat & middle
    tosavefilename = dateformat & "_" & middle
    MsgBox "The file name to be saved is " & tosavefilename
    Set ExcRange = ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("F" & i)
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Activate
    ExcRange.Copy
    wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdApp.Selection.Paste
    'saveasname = Environ("Userprofile")
    'Application.Wait Second(Now) + 10
    'wdApp.Activate
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs "test"

    ActiveDocument.Close
    wdApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: `SaveAs` needs a full filename and path, not just a word.

Comment: Even full name also does not work same error keeps coming

Comment: Then please edit your question so that it shows what you are actually using instead of "test"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method instead. It saves the specified document with a new name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the `Save As` dialog box (File tab).

The `filename` parameter stands for the name for the document. The default is the current folder and file name. If the document has never been saved, the default name is used (for example, Doc1.doc). If a document with the specified file name already exists, the document is overwritten without prompting the user.

Comment: I tried Saveas and saveas2 both and have been getting error Run time error 4248

Comment: Have you tried doing that manually? Do you get any errors? Have you tried to specify a valid file name?

Comment: Run-time error '4248' 
This command is not available because no document is open.
I have been getting this error consistently.

Comment: The [Documents.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add) method returns a `Document` object that represents a new, empty document added to the collection of open documents. Where do you use it?

Comment: I used it to copy and paste the contents in the cell of the excel sheet